# How to get the cell value of an intersection between 2 named ranges in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I am trying to get a value of an intersection of 2 named ranges.

Been searching for a solution for a while now, but can't seem to find any.

So lets say I have a table like this:

```
#     Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
Row1 |  1 |  6 |  3 |  4 |
Row2 |  6 |  7 |  4 |  2 |
Row3 |  4 | 13 |  9 | 12 |
Row4 | 12 |  3 | 18 | 14 |
```

These rows and columns are named ranges so Col1 = Sheet!B:B and Row1 = Sheet!2:2 etc.

Now how do I get the value from Col2 Row3 for example?

I have tried `=Col2 Row3` and vice versa but it doesn't seem to work that way.

Edit: Here's an example of what I'm trying to do
[image]

Thanks in advance,

Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the baseline would be:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3, 2))
```

where row and column can be easily substituted with formulas

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I fully understand how I can make this so it accomplishes what I'm looking for. Could you take a loot at https://imgur.com/a/jGrHSM1

Comment: Aha amazing! Thank you very much :) Edit: quick follow-up question. How would this work if I want to fetch the info from another tab?

Comment: Oh nevermind, I got it working now using: `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH("Magnesium"; Stoffen; 0); MATCH("Banaan"; Voedsel; 0); 4; 1; "Blad2"))`

Answer (score 1):

Use `INDEX`/`MATCH` :

```
=INDEX(A:E,MATCH(B11,A:A,0),MATCH(B10,1:1,0))
```

[image]

Comment: I think I explained it a bit wrong, I am trying to make a chart with nutrition information and then I'm trying to pick for example the magnesium amount of a banana. Look at this https://imgur.com/a/jGrHSM1